# Closure example what part does self invoking do

Tags: javascript, function, scope, closures

I am putting forward 2 examples of closure. First works fine, while second doesn't. Now, I don't understand why second scenario fails. It still is calling anonymous function 3 times and must also give same result of closure.

**Example 1:** (Works Fine)

```html
<html> 
<head></head>
<body>
<script>

var alpha1 = (function alpha(){
var a = 5; 
function beta(){
    a = a + 5; 
    alert(a);
    return a;
} 
return beta; 
})();
alpha1();
alpha1();
alpha1();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Example 2:** (Does not work and gives no error)

```html
<html> 
<head></head>
<body>
<script>

var alpha1 = function alpha(){
var a = 5; 
function beta(){
    a = a + 5; 
    alert(a);
    return a;
} 
return beta; 
};
alpha1();
alpha1();
alpha1();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, in 2nd example I am still calling the function alpha1 3 times; though I did not initiate it as IIFE (in 1st example) still I manually called it and it must work as closure. Shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

> Now, in 2nd example I am still calling the function alpha1 3 times;

Difference in first and second one is - **First `alpha1` is the handle to the return value of function `alpha`** (`beta`). Every time you call `alpha1();`, it invokes same `beta`.

While **Second `alpha1` is the handle to function `alpha1` itself**. Every time you call `alpha1();`, it returns you new `beta`.

Answer (score 0):

in you first example `IIFE` returns the function to `alpha1` variable so its works when you call `alpha1`

```html
<html> 
<head></head>
<body>
<script>

var alpha1 = function (){
var a = 5; 
function beta(){
    a = a + 5; 
    alert(a);
    return a;
} 
return beta; 
};
const resp = alpha1();
resp()
resp()
resp()
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still not a closure. Values are 10, 10, 10.